# How can i get the Parent Categories with C#? (Dot Net Fiddle included)

Tags: c#, linq

To demonstrate what is going on here i created this [Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gSOaav)

```
var list = new List<Category>()
{
    new Category() { Id = 1, TitleEN = "Category 1" }, 
    new Category() { Id = 2, TitleEN = "Category 2", ParentCategoryId = 1 }, 
    new Category() { Id = 3, TitleEN = "Category 3", ParentCategoryId = 2 }, 
    new Category() { Id = 4, TitleEN = "Category 4" }, 
    new Category() { Id = 5, TitleEN = "Category 5" }
};
```

This works like a charm on getting the `Child categories` of my model by Id.

```
var children = GetChildrenCategories(list, 1);
```

which outputs

```
Category 2
Category 3
```

Now i need to accomblish the opposite. How can i get the `Parent Categories` by Id?

For entering

```
var children = GetParentCategories(list, 3);
```

should result to

```
Category 1
Category 2
```

Comment: Why `GetParentCategories(list, 3)` should result in 1 and 2? is it because 3's parent is 2 and grandparent is 1?

Comment: you are using multilevel structure (tree) did you think using another efficient data structure like map or adjacency list while searching?

Comment: and could you please provide us with your thoughts or what you already did, it is a search problem you can use a lot of techniques DFS is a great candidate in this situation. 

if you are planning to use linq (it is self join relationship) I'm not sure this exist in linq.

Comment: @OfirD Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using DFS here is Example

```
     public static void GetParentsCategories(IEnumerable<Category> entities, List<string> parents, int? nodeId = null)
    {
        var currentNode = entities.Where(x => x.Id == nodeId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentNode == null)
            return;
        var parent = entities.Where(x => x.Id == currentNode.ParentCategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (parent == null)
            return;
        parents.Add(parent.TitleEN);
        GetParentsCategories(entities, parents, parent.Id);
    }
```

just pass parents as parameter after call you can check the result.

EDIT here another version with Iterator :

```
   public static IEnumerable<string> GetParentsCategories(IEnumerable<Category> entities,  int? nodeId = null)
    {
        var currentNode = entities.Where(x => x.Id == nodeId).FirstOrDefault();
        var parent = entities.Where(x => x.Id == currentNode.ParentCategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (parent == null)
            yield break;
        yield return parent.TitleEN;
         foreach (var trail in GetParentsCategories(entities, parent.Id))
            yield return (trail);

    }
```

Comment: time complexity is not the best thing O(N)2
you can use different datastructure and may be you got even O(n) solution.

Comment: That is great! Thanks. Should i also use Reverse() in results returned by GetParentsCategories function?

Comment: you can do reverse but it depends in the logic. 
you can read the list form the end too.

Comment: you can also update function parameters if available to contains parent id if available this will optimize the runtime too not very much, but little :D